# Output of a perltex function as input to a latex function

Tags: conditionals, perl

I'm in trouble with a simple (in theory) but quite annoiying problem in calling the ifthenelse function when I use the ouput of another function defined in perl as input. I'm using the perltex and the ifthen packages.
This is the code:

```
\perlnewcommand{\getX}{$x ="foo"; return $x}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\getX}{foo}}
{option1}
{option2}
```

this is the error that I get:

> ! Argument of @iinput has an
> extra }.

The perl function works, but I can't understand how to provide it's output to the ifthenelse function. I've tried many different approaches but none of them works. I think there are some theorical aspects behind this problem that I can't grab. Can anyone help me?